# Web server caching

Tags: linux, nginx

Could you please help me to better understand how the web server caching mechanism works.
I have a Wordpress website with opcode caching (`APC`). Pages are cached in memory via `W3 total cache` plugin.

- Is this plugin take care of the user session management?
- Is it possible to configure the web server that it will cache the content to `APC` directly, without this plugin.
- What's the recommended solution in this case?

I've tried with `nginx` and `FastCGI` cache but apparently this it's not generally safe as it may cause private pages (and/or cookies) to be cached and returned to other clients.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to, i would recommend to go with Memcached. It's the standard way to do it and there are [many plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/memcached) for Wordpress. It worth a try!